# NoReverseMatch at account/reset/done in django password reset feature

Tags: python, django

I am using django(1.10) default password reset feature.I am getting the below error when I change the password from the password reset form.

```
Reverse for 'login' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Template error:
In template C:\pyprojects\cias\ciasproj\ciassite\templates\registration\password_reset_complete.html, error at line 5
   Reverse for 'login' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []   1 : {% extends 'base.html' %}
   2 : 
   3 : {% block content %}
   4 :   <p>
   5 :     Your password has been set. You may go ahead and <a href=" {% url 'login' %} ">sign in</a> now.
   6 :   </p>
   7 : {% endblock %}
```

register/password_reset_complete.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
  <p>
    Your password has been set. You may go ahead and <a href="{% url 'login' %}">sign in</a> now.
  </p>
{% endblock %}
```

accounts/urls.py --

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r"^signup/$", views.signup, name="account_signup"),
    #url(r'^login/$', views.login, {'template_name': 'accounts/login.html'}, name='login'),
    url(r'^login/', views.login_view, name='account_login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.logout, {'next_page': '/account/login'}, name='logout'),
    url(r'^confirmemail/$', views.confirmemail, name='account_confirmemail'),
    url(r'^activate/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',views.activate, name='activate'),
    url(r'^activate/',views.activate, name='empty_activate'),
        url(r'^password_reset/$', auth_views.password_reset, name='password_reset'),
    url(r'^password_reset/done/$', auth_views.password_reset_done, name='password_reset_done'),
    url(r'^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,23})/$',
        auth_views.password_reset_confirm, name='password_reset_confirm'),
    url(r'^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',
    auth_views.password_reset_confirm, name='password_reset_confirm'),
    url(r'^reset/done/$', auth_views.password_reset_complete, name='password_reset_complete'),
]
```

I tried to modify the html link as

```
{% url reverse('account_login:login') %}
```

But that is giving another error --

```
Could not parse the remainder: '('account_login:login')' from 'reverse('account_login:login')'
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes that worked but lost the login template.But got an error in login page. `login() got an unexpected keyword argument 'template_name'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's a simple thing you are missing here. Whatever name you are giving there in the url list, you can use only that. If there is an app with a registered namespace, you have to use that.

In this case, you have defined the things directly and you should use the urls in that way only.

Instead of {% url 'login' %} it should be  {% url 'account_login' %}.

Just the name you have given to url pattern.